# Output printing Boolean instead of String

Tags: java

I am currently working on a method which outputs into a list all the subject codes which contain the string input by the user (s). For example, my ArrayList has 4 books which have two fields: name, subjectCode. Currently, the output for the method returns // True, False, False, True, etc. How do i configure it so it displays the subjectCode for all the True values eg. COMM100, COMM200 when input s = COM

```
private static void findSubjectCodes(ArrayList<Subject2> list, String s) {
    System.out.println("Subject codes found:");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i).subjectCode.contains(s) + "\n");

        // True, False, True, etc

}
```

Comment: Use an if statement, as `contains` returns a boolean.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve], then edit your question accordingly. Meanwhile, [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) does return a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of `.contains(*)` is boolean, that is why you are getting boolean value as output.

It is basically checking whether the said attribute contains the received text , hence `list.get(i).subjectCode.contains(s)` is printing a boolean value.

To print the subject code you need to do something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
       if(list.get(i).subjectCode.contains(s))
       {
          System.out.println("Subject is found:" +list.get(i).subjectCode);
       }
       else{
          System.out.println("Subject not found.");
       }
    }
```

Here is the official documentation :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Put your `contains` condition into a conditional branch. e.g.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
     String subjectCode = list.get(i);
     if (subjectCode.contains(s) {
             System.out.prinltn(subjectCode + "\n");
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.